# Sidekiq not closing postgresql connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

My Rails 4.1 sidekiq application is running into an issue with the active record connections to postgresql not being closed.

Since the connections are not being closed postgres is not releasing the memory and after a while I run out of memory on my postgres server(I have 15GB of ram and a fairly small database).

The other issue is that after awhile my sidekiq workers start to take about 10X as long as they should to run, and after a time the workers just get stuck and stop processing any new jobs.

I have tried wrapping my worker code in the following to no affect:

```
def with_connection(&block)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
    yield block
  end
ensure
  ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
end
```

I have also added this in my unicorn.rb file in the after_fork method

```
if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] || Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
  config['reaping_frequency'] = 10 # seconds
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
end
```

Is there anything I can do to get these connections to close, or at least release the postgres memory?

Comment: Are you certain that it's the open connections which are causing your memory load? That would be quite unusual.

Comment: I am pretty sure, I read that postgres will not release the memory back until the connection has been closed.  I watch the used memory on my postgres server increase as my workers run, but not decrease once the workers stop running.  Only restarting the application will free the memory.

Comment: It would be worth knowing exactly what is causing that memory burn. You typically want your connections to persist, as connection overhead is substantial; if you have cursors that are being held open indefinitely long or something, you're going to have issues, but that is a configuration issue rather than an app issue.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server may be useful - pay attention to `work_mem` and `shared_buffers`.

Comment: I have seen this article, and increased the shared_buffers to 6 of the 15GB on the server and left work_mem as the default.

Comment: This issue can also present itself as a ```psql: FATAL:  too many connections for role "foobar"``` for heroku users (or other users with n number of connections available) — when i scale down or up a dyno running sidekiq the parent sk process and its children all do not shut down their connections to PG, and then open another set. This quickly exhausts your 20 connection limit (or whatever it may be) — IMO this has nothing to do with pool sizes.

Comment: @stefanie What did you figure out for your situation?